# How to secure your socket connection in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have implemented a simple chat application using node js and MongoDB. But I want it to be secure as I have implemented JWT authorization for the user in my application. but don't know what it the best way to secure my socket connection.

Comment: https://github.com/auth0-community/auth0-socketio-jwt

Comment: use [session.socket.io](https://github.com/wcamarao/session.socket.io) it's easy with less custom-code to be written

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "secure your socket connection"?  Perhaps you should be using TLS?